# URL not updating with latest page changes

Tags: jsp, url, redirect

I have a problem that is very similar to this one: [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one)

It is actually the same very problem but happens in different situations, and it is when I use a `<jsp:forward>` tag

To put you in situation, I have a form that asks for an user and pass to perform login. This redirects to a new page (checklogin.jsp) that performs the checking, updates the session and if everything is ok then it goes like this:

```
  if (con.comprobarUserPass(passmd5)) { // We check everything is OK
           sesion.setAttribute("conexion", con);
           sesion.setAttribute("pass", passmd5);
  %>
  <jsp:forward page="index.jsp"/> //forwards to the index
  <%
  } else {
  %>
  <jsp:forward page="login.jsp"> // user/pass error, goes back to the login.jsp page
     <jsp:param name="error" value="<strong><span style=\"color:red;\">Usuario y/o clave incorrectos. <br>Vuelve a intentarlo.</span></strong>"/>
  </jsp:forward>
  <%               }
  } catch (userPassIncorrectoException e) {
  %>
  <jsp:forward page="login.jsp">
     <jsp:param name="error" value="<strong><span style=\"color:red;\">Usuario y/o clave incorrectos. <br>Vuelve a intentarlo.</span></strong>"/>
  </jsp:forward>
  <%                       }
  %>
```

Well, the problem appears here, even if I'm redirected to the index.jsp page or to the login.jsp page my url is:

`http://localhost:8084/myContext/checklogin.jsp`

Any ideas why this is happening? It's making the debug process realy harder than it should be.

Comment: and how are you calling `checklogin.jsp`? Using javascript ?

Comment: @HardikMishra Mishra nope, the form that asks for the user and pass has it as action: `<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="checklogin.jsp">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by using `response.sendRedirect("pageToGo");` and inserting a page between the form submit and the actual page I need to go after submitting.

This way the form will call the intermediary web that only redirects to the page the user has to see after submitting the form.